# System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed' error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm usign .net 6.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types;
using Store.Application.Interfaces.Contexts;
using Store.Application.Services.Users.Queries.GetUsers;
using Store.Persistence.Contexts;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataBaseContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

builder.Services.AddTransient<IGetUsersService, GetUsersService>();
var app = builder.Build();
```

I got this error:

> System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Store.Application.Services.Users.Queries.GetUsers.IGetUsersService Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: Store.Application.Services.Users.Queries.GetUsers.GetUsersService': Unable to resolve service for type 'Store.Application.Interfaces.Contexts.IDataBaseContext' while attempting to activate 'Store.Application.Services.Users.Queries.GetUsers.GetUsersService'.)'

my class:

```
public class GetUsersService : IGetUsersService
{
    private readonly IDataBaseContext _context;
    public GetUsersService(IDataBaseContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `DataBaseContext` implement `IDataBaseContext`? You might just use `DataBaseContext` in your `GetUsersService`

Answer (score 1):

Your class is expecting a `IDataBaseContext` but you have not told the DI container how to craft that object. All you need to do is use the [overload of the `AddDbContext` extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.entityframeworkservicecollectionextensions.adddbcontext?view=efcore-7.0#microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-entityframeworkservicecollectionextensions-adddbcontext-2(microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-iservicecollection-system-action((system-iserviceprovider-microsoft-entityframeworkcore-dbcontextoptionsbuilder))-microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-servicelifetime-microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-servicelifetime)) to specify the interface that the context implements:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<IDataBaseContext, DataBaseContext>(...)
```